# How can I insert the Crystal Report Page Footer for VB.NET Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

This report page Footer is already have. But I missing the Page footer Section delete.
so I want to insert the page footer again.....

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a blank part of any section of the report in the designer view (not the preview). From the context menu choose "Report" & then "Select Expert...".  From the Section Expert you can see the Report Footer (the very last section), and you can add extra sub sections, suppress, hide, unhide and so on.

Comment: +1...you cannot delete page section. probably made it really small.